# How do I loop through and read values from a nested array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of data like:

```
var messageArr = [
  messageA: [
    weight: 1,
    type: "pop up",
    content: "lorem ipsum",
  ],
  messageB: [
    weight: 3,
    type: "tile",
    content: "Hello world",
  ],
]
```

I am looping through it like:

```
    for (var key of Object.keys(messageArr )) {
      console.log(messageArr.content);
    }
```

But I cannot output the nested array items - nothing appears in console.

Would anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: `console.log(messageArr.content);` -> `console.log(messageArr[key].content);`

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ. Want to make that an answer?